# Getting 404 - No message found after migrating to Spring Boot 2.x

Tags: java, spring-boot

After I made all the necessary changes to migrate from Spring Boot 1.5.4 to 2.1.1, I'm getting a 404 not found error. I think it is something with the controller's url mapping.
I've made sure my main class and controllers are in correct place as I've placed my controller package after the main class.
I've also used @ComponentScan and @SpringBootApplication annotations.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/feature")
public class FeatureController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public String getFeatureForuser(@PathVariable("user_id") String userEId) {
            LOGGER.info("Fetching the avaliable features for User: {}", userEId);
            // Invoke the service layer.
            return service.getFeatureForuser(userEId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe `value = "/user"`? Or maybe app root changed for some reasons

Comment: Where (which package) did you add `@ComponentScan`?

Comment: Maybe you added `@SpringBootApplication` at the package that is not parent package of `FeatureController` package

Comment: @Spara I've added SpringBootApplication at the package that is parent package of FeatureController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it after I changed server.contextPath to server.servlet.context-path in application.properties file because from Spring Boot 2.x a number of servlet specific properties have changed from server.* to server.servlet.*.

I hope this will be helpful. Thanks you all for helping!

Answer (score -1):

did you try @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = " give your base package")

also the @RequestMapping(value = "user" should be @RequestMapping(value = "/user"

Comment: I know you are a new contributor and you like to gain more reputation, but NEVER COPY OTHER ANSWERS AND MAKE A POST BY YOUR NAME!